# oracle database and ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I'm building an ASP MVC application, and i got error ORA-06413 when I'm connecting to Oracle databases. Connection can't open !

I have 8.1.7 client.

Here is my test code :

```
OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection("Provider=msdaora; Data Source=AGILEDSV; user id=reader; password=reader;");
        try
        {
            c.Open();
            c.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Surprisingly this code working well with a Console application

Comment: 8i client?  what version server?  (and use odp.net)

Comment: Tried on 11g and 10.2, same issue on both versions.
However i can connect from a clean console application, but in my asp mvc application this code is include in a method call by an ajax request, might it be the source of my problem ?

Comment: I tried from Index() method in my controller, having the same issue.
So that's not a problem from ajax call

Comment: you should really use odp.net to access Oracle from .NET  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: are you on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Yes, i m on 64-bit machine. ODP ok however i need a connection to Oracle 8 database.